# Getting two bootstrap tabs to work on a single page and accessing the active tab on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have two bootstrap tab components on my page

The first one has two tabs and the second one has three.

The simplified code is as below..

```
    <div class="col-md-12">

  <ul id="tab1" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#taba" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab A</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab B</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab1content" class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="taba">
 Tab A
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabb">
Tab B
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">

  <ul id="tab2" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabx" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab X</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#taby" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab Y</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab Z</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab2content" class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabx">
 Tab X
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="taby">
Tab Y
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabz">
Tab Z
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnspl" style="max-width:100%" />
```

On submit button press I need to find out the active tab in both the components of the page.

I found this code in bootstrap site.. but it is for a single tab..

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

What changes would be needed when there are two bootstrap tab components.

jsfiddle(not working) : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13447/

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can use `href="#tabId"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding it right you need to know which tab is active in both the components when "submit" button is correct. To get it you can use following code in button's click handler:

```
var x=$("#tab1content  div.active").prop("id");
var y=$("#tab2content  div.active").prop("id");
$("#log").text("TAB 1: "+ x +"\r\nTAB 2: "+ y);
```

`x` and `y` contains the `id` of selected/active tab in respective tab components. Here is working <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/52VtD/13450/)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the currently active tab you can check within click event of submit button hasClass(".active").attr("id").

The second tab container id is same as the first tab container id.

Comment: I made that mistake while creating the simplified code.., now rectified in question

Comment: So do I need to add an id to <li>

Comment: You can use hasClass(".active").next("a").attr("href"). From this will have a particular selctor and you can do any thing with that... all though you can use id too and really am not sure what you want to do with it. Once you know which tab has class active you can do anything with that.

Comment: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'next'

Comment: What you want achieve with it. Am actually not getting. Once you know what tab is active in page you can do do with that tab anything. Like li hasClass active . Than make addClass bg-success to it or anything you like

Comment: Buddy I am over phone so can not help with codeing it.